# How to generate NES palette in C# code

Tags: palette

How can I generate the NES palette entirely in C# code, without using any constant values?

I want to precalculate the palette in the same way that the PPU does.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Show us you have done some research on the topic.

Comment: I think a guy had a formula once upon a time on nesdev. Or used one to generate his. I think his name was bmrNUMBERS. Maybe kevtris had one too. Where are you using this palette? in an emulator? in a game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate the chip based on the YPbPr signals the NES sents, but just make it easy for yourself and pre-program the colors using the hex values from wikipedia or some other source.